# MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, lg, malformedurlexception

I am getting `MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol` while connecting to my app server. When I checked details of the exception it shows

> unexpected end of stream on connection

It is only happening in LG K8 V Android version 6.0.1

On all other phones the same code works fine. I am not able to understand what is wrong with this phone.

On Debugging I found that on the devices it works `HttpUrlConnection` object contains

> com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpUrlConnectionDelegate:https://myurl

and on devices it does not work the `HttpUrlconnection` object is like

> com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl:https://myurl

`HttpUrlConnectionDelegate` is missing on LG K8V.

Comment: The first is using **Https**URLConnectionImpl. The second uses **Http**URLConnectionImpl

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes. But why. I am using HttpsUrlConnection class only. Why does it try to make http connection just on LG K8 V ?

Comment: Not entirely sure. You could try using another HTTP library like Volley or OkHttp